# Efficient way to do congruent transformation using matrix inverse?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrix, eigenvalues, inverse, matrix-factorization

I know a square self-adjoint matrix $S_{vv}$ and I want to find:

$S_{rr} = HS_{vv}H^{\dagger}$

where $\dagger$ denotes conjugate transpose.

I do not know $H$ but I do know $H^{-1}$.

What is the most efficient way to solve something of this form?

I have considered rewriting it as:

$S_{rr} = H(HS_{vv})^{\dagger}$

Finding the LU decomposition of $H^{-1}$, and then doing two lots of forward and back substitutions to solve for $S_{rr}$.  But it feels like there might be a better way?

Any help much appreciated.

Comment: $H^{-1}$ is not singular, right?

Comment: As a general rule, any time you are tempted to compute the explicit inverse of a matrix, there is a better way.  I'm not sure what it's called when solves $R=A^{-1}V(A^{-1})^{\dagger}$ for $V$, given known $R$ and $A$, but it has at least one obvious solution.

For example, I might case this as $AX^{\dagger}=V$ and solve for $X$, then solve $X=AR$ for $R$.  You can use LU for this, of course.

Comment: Thanks Jeff, yes $H^{-1}$ is not singular.

Comment: I agree that it can be done that way, as I indicated in my question. But I'm wondering what "the" way is to approach this problem, if such a thing exists. The thing is, like you, I don't know what to call this so it is difficult to search for a good reference.

Comment: If you're looking for a congruent transform, LDL is probably a better choice.

Comment: I would guess:

 (1.) Decompose $S_{vv} = LDL^\dagger$, so that $S_{rr} = HL\,D\,(HL)^\dagger$

 (2.) Solve for $B=HL$ from $H^{-1}B = L$

 (3.) Compute $S_{rr} = BDB^\dagger$.

Comment: A final thought. The answer depends also on what you are going to do with $S_{rr}$: if it is just a few computations of $x\,S_{rr}x^\dagger$, then computation of $D, B$ as per my comment above will suffice.